# C# Most efficient way to read file content, replace some content and finally load it as XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to read file content and make some replacements on it. After that, the initial file with the replacements is loaded as XDocument. I have made a 2 different implementations:

implementation1:

```
string contents1 = File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName, new UTF8Encoding(true));

File.WriteAllText(fileInfo.FullName, methodForReplacements(contents1), new UTF8Encoding(true));

return XDocument.Load(fileInfo.FullName, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

implementation2:

```
string contents;

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileInfo.FullName))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, new UTF8Encoding(true)))
    {
        contents = methodForReplacements(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileInfo.Name, false, new UTF8Encoding(true)))
{
    sw.Write(contents);
}
return XDocument.Load(fileInfo.FullName, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

replacementMethod():

```
private string methodForReplacements(string contents)
{
    string replaced = new StringBuilder(contents)
        .Replace("\r", "&#x0D;")
        .Replace("\n", "&#x0A;")
        .ToString();

    return replaced;
}
```

After some benchmarking (10000 iterations, filesize: 265KB, numberOfReplacements: 10), it seems that the 2 implementations take very much the same time to execute (implementation1: 99sec, implementation2: 97sec). Is there any other more optimized and efficient way to achieve the same output?

Comment: Check out this article, it might help: https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files 
According to the aurhor's finding, there is not much difference between  regular reader or buffered reader.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a three task block process.  so as long as you don't need to read ahead to know what you have to inert into the XDocument, what you can do is as you read in each line of input file, look for characters that need to be replaced, and then write out input line with changes. Between the input line and changed content, I gather you have enough information and content to decide what needs to go to the XDocument to respond accordingly.  That'll save you some time.